# next method (Class.first) doesn't work after Rails update 4.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause, argument-error

I have a model which look like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :level

    def next
        Question.first(:conditions => ['id > ? AND level_id = ?', self.id, self.level_id], :order => 'id ASC') 
    end

end
```

This worked perfectly fine, until i updated by rails to version 4.1.0.
Now i receive this error:

> ArgumentError in QuestionsController#answer invalid value for
>   Integer(): "{:conditions=>[\"id > ? AND level_id = ?\""

I can't figure out how to fix this. is it possibly that the rails update is responsible for this problem? I have exactly the same method in another application and that one still works.

Comment: How are you calling this function???

Answer (score 4):

The method `first` has changed with Rails 4.

Up to Rails 3.2, it would accept condition arguments, and your implementation would work. Here is the [original documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first), notice how it checks the type of `*args` before using them.

In Rails 4 the method changed ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first)), and now it only accepts an integer limit.

You should update your implementation with:

```
def next
  Question.where('id > ? AND level_id = ?', id, level_id).order(id: :asc).first 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: this should work

```
Question.where("id > ? AND level_id = ?", id, level_id).order("id asc").first
```

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately, it throwed the following error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in QuestionsController#answer
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "'id > 1 AND level_id = 1) ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 1": SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE ('id > 1 AND level_id = 1) ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 1

Comment: Weird. Can you try it in the console, and add the output to your question?

Comment: Also, again in the console, try it with hardcoded values in the SQL statement: `where("id > 1 AND level_id = 1")`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
Question.where('id > ? AND level_id = ?', self.id, self.level_id).order(id: :asc).first
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first), the `first` method takes an integer, not a string.

I don't remember it ever taking a string either, as the method description indicates it returns the first N records. Maybe that particular method was never called until you did an update and did some other changes.

You can use the `where` method, which takes your conditions, and then use `first` to get the first result.

```
Question.where(:conditions => ['id > ? AND level_id = ?', self.id, self.level_id], :order => 'id ASC').first
```